# sound stops working on xfce 11.10

Tags: sound, xfce

I installed Ubuntu 11.10, then turned it into XFCE.  It works, but sometimes the audio will stop working, requiring a reboot to fix it.  This will happen in the middle of a video, played using vlc.  I'm on a Dell Latitude E6400.  This never happened on a straight Ubuntu distro in almost 2 years of use, so I'm pretty sure it's not the hardware.

What do I do to diagnose this problem when it happens again?

Comment: +1 I have a similar problem. Using a Thinkpad T60, Ubuntu 11.10, and Xfce 4.8-- no sound whatsoever.

Comment: I've given up on straight Ubuntu, preferring instead the fast, clean Unity free Linux Mint LXDE. I've had no problems with it so far.

Comment: What happens with fresh Xubuntu install?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).